# Problem with click corner of fabricjs using threejs raycast

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js, fabricjs

i'm trying to recreate this [app](https://www.owayo.com/konfigurator_html/index.php?sport=football&product=shirts_f3&lang=en&land=us#), and it is currently working now. But i can't click the corner of the text perfectly, it always need to be offset.

https://jsfiddle.net/naonvl/ecdxfkbm/3/

right now, it's hard to scale the text. i think the `getRealPosition` is not correct so the mouse X and Y also not precise.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is i set `getIntersects` like this

```
var getIntersects = function (point, objects) {
  mouse.set(point.x * 2 - 0.97, -(point.y * 2) + 0.97);
  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
  return raycaster.intersectObjects(objects);
};
```

compare to three.js example here https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_raycast_texture

```
function getIntersects( point, objects ) {
  mouse.set( ( point.x * 2 ) - 1, - ( point.y * 2 ) + 1 );
  raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
  return raycaster.intersectObjects( objects, false );    
}
```

i miss calculate the `mouse.set` there, i change the calculation and tweak X and Y position of mouse by adding 3 to each of them, and it raycasted perfectly in the center of mouse pointer